# Shadowbox - elements positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning, shadowbox

I am using default Shadowbox script. My page: http://www.sildev.pl/shadowbox/index.html

I need to change the position of title, counter and close button elements.

This screen shows what I need:
http://www.sildev.pl/schema.png

How to do this?

Thx for any help. Regards.

Comment: you will find everything you can configure on shadowbox right here: http://www.shadowbox-js.com/options.html. I found Shadowbox very inflexible in manners of styling... Maybe you want to use something else like fancybox, or programm something your self. I don't recommend editing the fancybox code (its pretty messy)

Comment: Options of Shadowbox can't help me! Fancybox is very messy as you said. I need a good solution with image step counter.

Comment: ohhh mistake i meant the shadowbox code, not fancybox... fancybox is fine ;)

Comment: But how to set up in Fancybox a step image counter like in Shadowbox? I need this function very much.

Comment: I use Fancybox, add some JS code and... it works! Thx anyway.